# I want to get values between ranges of javascript array

Tags: javascript

**Here is my array i am trying to set the values of array how can i do it using loop. **

```
when i provide the range like i want to get (14.28,42.84) result will be (J,I,H).


var arr = [];
arr[14.28] = "J";
arr[28.56] = "I";
arr[42.84] = "H";
arr[57.12] = "G";
arr[71.40] = "F";
arr[85.68] = "E";
arr[99.96] = "D";
var citrus = arr.slice(values);
alert(citrus);
```

what if i have values between (0,100) what should i set?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkKX8.png)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not looking for an Array if you want that kind of functionality.
You can make your own class or something.

```
class RangeThingy {
  constructor() {
    this.vals = [];
  }

  set(number, value) {
    this.vals.push({
      number,
      value,
    });
  }

  getRange(start, end) {
    return this.vals.filter(val => start <= val.number && val.number <= end).map(val => val.value);
  }
}
const range = new RangeThingy();
range.set(14.28, 'J');
range.set(28.56, 'I');
range.set(42.84, 'H');
range.set(57.12, 'G');
// etc...
range.getRange(14.28, 42.84) // returns ['J', 'I', 'H']
```

Comment: what if i have values between (0,100) what should i set?

Comment: well, when you call `range.set` you provide it with the location of the value and the value. If you want to get all the values between 0 and 100 inclusive, just call `range.getRange(0, 100)`

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing isn't invalid in terms of JavaScript sytanx, but doesn't make sense because you cannot iterate over the array using regular methods. The statements like these:

```
arr[14.28] = "J";
```

are basically assigning custom properties to the array, instead of setting items to array indices (try getting the keys using `Object.keys(arr)`), making it more complex to retrieve values.

I suggest to use JavaScript objects for this purpose. Those allow you to assign arbitrary key/value pairs, but one caveat is that the key ordering is not guaranteed.

The following is an attempt to solve your problem using objects. This may not be a full-proof solution, but it tries to guide you in the right direction for achieving such tasks.

```js
let obj = {};
obj[14.28] = "J";
obj[28.56] = "I";
obj[42.84] = "H";
obj[57.12] = "G";
obj[71.40] = "F";
obj[85.68] = "E";
obj[99.96] = "D";

// Returns the items in the specific range
function getRange(a, b) {
  let
    // Get all the keys of the object
    keys = Object.keys(obj),

    // Get the start/end indices in object's keys so that
    // we can slice the keys array to get all the keys in the
    // specified range
    start = keys.findIndex(k => k == a),
    end = keys.findIndex(k => k == b),

    // Get all the keys in the specified range
    sliced = keys.slice(start, end + 1);

  // Returns the array of values for the keys
  return sliced.map(k => obj[k]);
}

console.log(getRange(14.28, 42.84));
```

Comment: @KhurramKhan -- If it works, please consider accepting the answer.